# How to install MPI into a QWIN project in Visual Studio 2015 with Intel Fortran Cluster Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, graphics, fortran, mpi, coding-efficiency

I use QWIN graphics to monitor what is happening during calculations. This is also a good help to reveal bugs. Now I have parallellized the code (running from the command line) but I want to return to the Visual Studio environment, as it has been very efficient up till now. There are instructions for  console projects but these do not give me Graphic windows.

Comment: What do you mean by *"install MPI into a project"*? One installs MPI to a computer, not to a project.

Comment: To be more specific: When I run my fortran code in the Visual Studio environment I must give the location of the MPI library etc. When I do this for a QWIN project, some more change seems to be necessary to make the graphics work.

Comment: Why does it seem necessary? Any error message? We cannot see inside your head why does it seem to you? Please see [ask]. Do not use commemts, but [edit] your question with more information.

Comment: When the code is run from the command line every rank correctly displays a graphic window with the plots. When Fortran is installed in Visual Studio and the path to the MPI library is given according to the Intel-VS instructions only one window is displayed, a console window for text display. I asked this question to Stack Overflow with the hope to find somebody who had worked with QWIN and MPI in the VS environment. Maybe this question should be asked in a Microsoft forum?

Comment: Rather the Intel Forum I suppose. Yes, you are more likely to find someone there in my opinion. Some Intel people come here from time to time, but it is more direct there.

Answer (score 0):

You will have difficulty with this. QuickWin (QWIN) makes a lot of assumptions, not the least of which is that there is a single user of the program who is running it from a Windows UI. With MPI, multiple instances of the program are run in parallel, none of which are connected to a Windows UI. Also, QuickWin has its own threading model - the UI has a thread and the executing code has another.

Since QuickWin gives you very little control over the environment, I don't see how to make this work with MPI. Even worse, QuickWin requires that the entire program be linked statically, which restricts some programming models.

It does seem that you can use auto-parallel or OpenMP with QuickWin - why not try that first?

Comment: Because of  a third party library with origin in the 1970's OpenMP cannot be used. I have, with aid from Intel, made Quick Win and MPI work together when the Fortran program is run from the command line. This is great! I am more than satisfied. Nevertheless, having worked with Intel Fortran, VS and QuickWin with great satisfaction for a number of years, I thought it should be possible to remain in the VS environment even with MPI added. This should save me the psxevars intel64 call and add some more efficiency. I can anyhow use VS for code modification and then run from the command line.

Comment: So, with that said by you, shall I conclude that running Fortran, QuickWin and MPI in Visual Studio is deemed to fail or is it worth a try. Does the fact that it seems to work from the command line tell you anything?

Comment: It should not matter from where you run it, but I assume you know that an MPI program can't be run by just naming the EXE - you need an mpirun or similar command. You can do this in VS by specifying the command on the Debugging property page in place of the EXE name.

Comment: I have done that according to the instructions published by Intel but instead of getting the same number of Graphic windows as size=number of ranks I get just a single console window.To be more precise, in VS-Configuration Properties-Debugging I write:

Comment: Command Arguments: -K -localroot -n 8 C:\code\x64\Debug\prog.exe

Comment: mpiexec is almost certainly a console application - there's no window context for QuickWin to create windows. Are you saying you get multiple QuickWin frame windows when you do this from the command line? That surprises me, but I've reached the end of the suggestions I can offer here.

Comment: Thanks Steve! I do get size graphic windows for size ranks! Any idea to talk to the Microsoft people on this matter?